# Distribution of $\frac{X_1X_3+X_2X_4}{\sqrt{X_3^2+X_4^2}}$

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables

> $X_1, X_2, X_3$ and $X_4$ are independent standard normal random variables. Find the distribution of $$T=\frac{X_1X_3+X_2X_4}{\sqrt{X_3^2+X_4^2}}$$

I have tried to do it by the following two approaches:

**1st approach:**

The conditional distribution of $T|X_3=x_3,X_4=x_4$ is $N(0,1)$, which is independent of $X_3$ and $X_4$.

So, $T$ follows $N(0,1)$.

**2nd approach:**

Let $U=X_1X_3+X_2X_4$ and $V=X_3^2+X_4^2$

By orthogonal transformation, I have found that $U$ follows Laplace distribution with parameters $(0,1)$. Also, $V$ follows Chi-square distribution with d.f. $2$. Clearly, $U$ and $V$ are independent. So,

Joint pdf of $(U,V)$ is,

$f_{U,V}(u,v)=\left(\frac{1}{2}e^{-|u|}\right)×\left(\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{v}{2}}\right)$

$=\frac{1}{4}e^{-(|u|+\frac{v}{2})}$, $u\in \mathbb{R} , v>0$

Consider the transformation $(U,V)\rightarrow (Z,W)$ where $Z=\frac{U}{\sqrt V}$ and $W=\sqrt V$

So, $u=zw, v=z^2$

Clearly, $z \in\mathbb{R}, w>0$

Jacobian of transformation is,

$J(\frac{u,v}{z,w})=\begin{vmatrix}w&z\\0&2w\end{vmatrix}=2w^2$

So, joint pdf of $(Z,W)$ is,

$f_{Z,W}(z,w)=f_{U,V}(zw,w^2)|J|$

$=\frac{1}{2}w^2e^{-(w|z|+\frac{w^2}{2})}$, $z \in\mathbb{R}, w>0$

Marginal pdf of $Z$ is,

$f_{Z}(z)=\int_0^{\infty}f_{Z,W}(z,w)dw$

$=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}w^2e^{-(w|z|+\frac{w^2}{2})}dw$

$=\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{z^2}{2}}\int_0^{\infty}w^2e^{-\frac{(w+|z|)^2}{2}}dw$

I am getting stuck here as I cannot solve this integration. I know that the 1st approach is much easier, but still I want to know whether I can solve it by the 2nd approach.

**Edit:** As StubbornAtom points out in the comment section that $U$ and $V$ may not be independent, I want to know:

1) Is there any way to check whether they are independent or not?

2) If $U$ and $V$ are not independent, then my 2nd approach is not correct because it was based on the fact that $U$ and $V$ are independent. Then, is there any alternate way to find the distribution of $T$ other than the 1st approach (like some kind of transformations)?

Comment: It's not obvious, that U has Laplace distribution, and also not obvious that U and V are independent. Can you show this?

Comment: Marginals of $U$ and $V$ are fine. But how are $U$ and $V$ independent? Note that unlike the distribution of $T$, distribution of $U$ given $X_3,X_4$ depends on $X_3,X_4$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Ohh, then $U$ and $V$ may not be independent. I have confused the marginal distribution with the conditional one. Can you please tell me, in that case, 1) How can I check whether $U$ and $V$ are independent? 2) The 2nd approach is of no use since I have done it using the fact that $U$ and $V$ are independent. Then is there any alternative way to find the distribution of $T$ other than the 1st approach? Like some kind of transformation?